# Como vejo o maior numero dum determinado conjunto de numeros bem como a sua média?

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Preciso de criar o código para um utilizador entrar com um número indeterminado de números e que veja depois o maior dos números e faça a sua média.

Cada entrada é feita clicando no **botão "confirmar"** (feito no *design* da *Form*) que vai acumulando os valores introduzidos e limpa-os de seguida, para isso criei uma variável `y` que vai acumulando os valores.

Quando o **botão "maior"** é premido, coloca numa outra `textbox` feita para o resultado, o maior dos números. O **botão "média"** deverá dar a *média* (também na `textbox` do resultado) dos números que entraram até ao momento.

É um problema mais ou menos simples penso, mas precisava de uma ajudinha. Envio em anexo o que fiz de código.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim y As Integer
    Private Sub btnconfirm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click
        Dim numeros(txtboxnum.Text) As Integer

        If IsNumeric(txtboxnum.Text) Then
            y = y + 1
            txtboxnum.clear()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Atenção, introduza um NÚMERO")
            Return
            txtboxnum.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnmaior_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmaior.Click
        Dim maior As String
        For c = 0 To txtboxnum.Text.Length - 1
            If txtboxnum.Text(y) > maior Then
                maior = txtboxnum.Text(y)
            End If
        Next
        txtboxresult.Text = maior

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnmedia_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmedia.Click
        For c = 0 To txtboxnum.Text.Length - 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnnovosnums_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnovosnums.Click
        txtboxnum.Clear()
        txtboxresult.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Crisp, você especificou tudo o que você tem que fazer, mas não esclareceu a sua real dificuldade.

Comment: @Fabricio a minha dificuldade é como é que eu faço para ver qual o maior número dum conjunto de números introduzido pelo utilizador e fazer a média dos mesmos

Comment: Você deve usar um *array* para guardar os números, e não somá-los.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, a variável `y` não é um *conjunto de números*, mas sim uma variável que você está usando para somar as entradas do `Textbox`, é necessário guardar os números num [`arrayList`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist-vbnet).

```
Dim numeros As New ArrayList
```

Para obter o maior número dum *array*, utilize a [função `Math.Max`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-max-min-vbnet):

```
Dim maiorNumero As Integer = 0
Dim total As Integer = 0

For Each numero As Integer In numeros
     total += numero
     maiorNumero = Math.Max(maiorNumero, numero)
Next
```

Para obter a média, você deve somar os números do *array* e dividi-lo pela quantidade de números:

```
Dim media As Integer = total / numeros.Count
```

**Nota**: É necessário usar `imports System.Collections`

[Ver **`demonstração`**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VzgTLT)

Comment: @crispypedro_ Você está adicionando a entrada do `textbox` na *array*?

Comment: como assim ? devo fazer: Dim numeros(txtboxnum.text) As ArrayList ?

Comment: @crispypedro_ Se possível apague os comentários anteriores. Você olhou o [**exemplo que postei**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VzgTLT)? Do jeito que você está fazendo, está errado.

Comment: olhei sim, mas na sua demonstração está a trabalhar com a sua Console Application não sei se advém daí o erro. para o botão maior eu pus o código "For Each numero..." e para o botão média pus o "Dim media As Integer = ..."

Comment: @crispypedro_ Veja esse exemplo com formulários: **http://pastebin.com/Um9DdZSL** Veja os comentários! qualquer coisa comente se não funcionar ou se possível, marque a resposta com o sinal ✔ abaixo da pontuação.

Comment: finalmente funciona, desculpe a massada! obrigado!!!